# is there a way to mimic a service like Mixpanel inside Azure?

Tags: javascript, azure, analytics

I need to send events to be stored somewhere i can later download or query them.

These events will be generated in a javascript file embedded in some high traffic pages, there will be about 10M+ events per month so i'm looking for something in Azure (where i have some credit), that can take these kinds of workloads, preferably in a automatic, auto-scalling, manner. Is there a way?

I've looked into some of the Azure products like Event Hub, it seems it can output into a Data Lake Store, so that would work, but it seems the event generators can't be in javascript.

I also looked into Google Analytics events, but i can't access ALL the data in there unless i have Analytics 360, which is too expensive.

Comment: Have you looked at Application Insights? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/

Comment: Yes i've glanced over it, but it seems focused on performance and exception logging, which isn't my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have looked into Event Hubs - that is a good start. EH can accept messages either in HTTP or AMQP. There are JavaScript libraries to help you wrap it:

- This one wraps HTTP in JS: https://github.com/ytechie/eventhubs-js
- This one from MS wraps AMQP for node.js: https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/tree/master/node

EH can also export events into a storage account using the relatively new "Archive" feature: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-archive-overview/

Alternatively you can use a SaaS solution like "Application Insights - Analytics" to send, store and query your events: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics/